# PostgreSQL for Windows

Tags: php, postgresql, psql

Basically i used to make web systems with php and mysql, I wanted to learn a new database system, i chose postgresql. I uninstalled xampp and installed postgresql-9.3.4-2-windows-x64 with PgAdmin III.

Question 1: How can i run my php files using postgre assuming im creating a new system from scratch. Like where do i put my php file? Do i still need to install xampp again? or just put my files inside a folder in the postgresql installation folders?

Question 2: How can i manage my databases using pgAdmin instead of phpPgAdmin or any browser based postgresql database manager.

Comment: "mysql is depreciated" that's news to me

Comment: I think you're a bit confused. From the docs, "The original MySQL extension is now deprecated, and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions." http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: nvm the deprecated thing, im dumb. I just want to start on with PSQL because i like how you can create functions inside the database and just call it on front end side. I just want to know how to make it work with my PHP and HTML, using PgAdmin instead of phpmyPgAdmin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL  is a database, you put your php files in a directory that Apache can serve, and configure Apache accordingly. You can start [here](https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp)

As for the how to use pgadmin, [RTM](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/).

Comment: I used wappstack before, and it lets me use phpmypgadmin instead of pgadmin, how can i connect pgadmin to wapp stack? So i need an apache server?

Comment: You need Apache to serve the php files, not to connect to pgadmin. To use pgadmin, install it and [follow the manual](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.18/connect.html)